# Update multiple documents with aggregated values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, updates, document

### Problem 1

I have a collection named `recipe` in which all docs have a array field `ingredients`. I want to count those array items and write them into a new field `ingredient_count`.

### Problem 2

There is also a collection named `ingredient`. The docs have a `count` field which is the total number of uses in all recipes.

### My Current Approach

My solution right now is a script that aggregates over the collection and updates all documents one by one:

```
// PROBLEM 1: update recipe documents
db.recipe.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                numberOfIngredients: { $size: "$ingredients" }
            }
        }
    ]
).forEach(function(recipe) {
    db.recipe.updateOne(
        { _id: recipe._id },
        { $set: { incredient_count: recipe.numberOfIngredients } }
    )
});

// PROBLEM 2: update ingredient documents
db.ingredient.find().snapshot().forEach(function(ingredient) {
    db.ingredient.updateOne(
        { _id: ingredient._id },
        { $set: { count: db.recipe.count({ ingredients: { $in: [ingredient.name] } })) } }
    )
});
```

This is **terribly slow**. Any idea how to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both problem it's possible to only perform aggregation that output to new collections that would replace existing one :

### Problem1

The aggregation contains one `$project` for counting ingredients with the list of field to keep :

```
db.recipe.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        ingredients: 1,
        numberOfIngredients: { $size: "$ingredients" }
    }
}, {
    $out: "recipeNew"
}])
```

that give you :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58155bc09c924e717c5c4240"), "ingredients" : [......], "numberOfIngredients" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58155bc19c924e717c5c4241"), "ingredients" : [......], "numberOfIngredients" : 3 }
```

The result of the aggregation is written to a new collection `recipeNew` that can replace the existing `recipe` collection

### Problem2

The aggregation contains :

- 1 `$unwind` to remove ingredients array
- 1 `$group` to sum occurence of each ingredients & group by ingredients `_id`
- 1 `$lookup` that join ingredients collection to the current aggregation to retrieve all fields for specified ingredients
- 1 `$unwind` to remove the array of imported ingredients items
- 1 `$project` to select fields to keep
- 1 `$out` to output the result to a new collection

Query is :

```
db.recipe.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$ingredients"
}, {
    $group: { _id: "$ingredients", IngredientsNumber: { $sum: 1 } }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "ingredients",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "ingredientsDB"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { path: "$ingredientsDB", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
}, {
    $project: {
        ingredientsNumber: "$IngredientsNumber",
        name: "$ingredientsDB.name"
    }
}, {
    $out: "ingredientsTemp"
}])
```

That gives :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b54"), "ingredientsNumber" : 2, "name" : "ingredients5" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b53"), "ingredientsNumber" : 1, "name" : "ingredients4" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b52"), "ingredientsNumber" : 2, "name" : "ingredients3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b51"), "ingredientsNumber" : 1, "name" : "ingredients2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b50"), "ingredientsNumber" : 2, "name" : "ingredients1" }
```

### The cons of this solution :

- It uses `$project` so you need to specify the fields to keep
- you will get a new `ingredientsTemp` collection containing only ingredients that are actually present in recipes so one additionnal aggregation with a `$lookup` should be necessary to join the existing one with the one you got from that aggregation :

The following will join the existing `ingredients` collection with the one we have created :

```
db.ingredients.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "ingredientsTemp",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "ingredientsDB"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { path: "$ingredientsDB", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
}, {
    $project: {
        name: "$name",
        ingredientsNumber: "$ingredientsDB.ingredientsNumber"
    }
}])
```

Then you would have :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b50"), "name" : "ingredients1", "ingredientsNumber" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b51"), "name" : "ingredients2", "ingredientsNumber" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b52"), "name" : "ingredients3", "ingredientsNumber" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b53"), "name" : "ingredients4", "ingredientsNumber" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b54"), "name" : "ingredients5", "ingredientsNumber" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5812caaeb4829937f4599b57"), "name" : "ingredients6" }
```

### The goods :

- It uses only aggregation so it should be quicker

Comment: This is golden, thanks for the great explanation and examples.